Why call is ambiguous between 'Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)' and 'Task.Run(Func<Task>) when passing method name
I am trying to have multiple non-async methods run at the same time as below. All functions are defined in the same class as member functions.
private string getEstimatedWaypointStart()
{
    return "id-1"; //...takes a long time to reach here
}

private string getEstimatedWaypointEnd()
{
    return "id-2"; //...takes a long time to reach here
}

private void postVector()
{
    //These don't compile
    Task t1 = Task.Run(getEstimatedWaypointStart);
    Task t2 = Task.Run(getEstimatedWaypointEnd);
    //These works fine
    Task t3 = Task.Run((Func<string>)getEstimatedWaypointStart); 
    Task t4 = Task.Run(() => getEstimatedWaypointEnd()); 

    /*do stuff*/
}

However, I'm getting unexpected compilation errors complaining about ambiguousness when I try to build the code:
CS0121  
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)' and 'Task.Run(Func<Task>)'

I've found this post having a really similar situation. However, in that post the delegate was not ambiguous after removing the unnecessary invoke since its type is defined in the method's parameter. I believe this is the same reason why a cast (Func<string>) fixes the problem for me. Not in my case though as the functions are just defined in the same class.
I'm not looking for a workaround since a lambda expression works fine. I am curious if there is an explanation of this behavior: Why the compiler is seeing the delegate as a Func<Task> when the async keyword is not used at all? Is this a bug in my current fairly old C# version (C# 7.3) or is this expected? If latter, should I just stick with the lambda expression?

Note that this actually works in the latest .NET (Core) - see the second answer.

compiles - @sharplab.io
